# Object Passing through Session in webforms asp.net

Tags: user-profile

I am working on asp.net webforms. There's is a user login page if user successfully login then it saves all the data in object of class profile data after accessing through sql  database

```
Profiledata profiledata = new Profiledata();
profiledata.Fname = SelectReader.GetString(0);
profiledata.Lname = SelectReader.GetString(1);
profiledata.email = SelectReader.GetString(2);
profiledata.password = SelectReader.GetString(3);
\\if we print profiledata values here all values are shown correct                                          
Session["profile"] = profiledata;
```

On the next page I am accessing

```
Profiledata profiledata = new Profiledata();
profiledata = (Profiledata)Session["profile"];
```

but it shows null exception in Session no value  found in session

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving session value before session is filled, it can be null.
It can be null also if you have disabled the SessionState http module or if your code runs in a HttpHandler, that does not specify either the IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState

Comment: Please go through this section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  to understand how answers should work. SO is not a forum where you discuss issues through answers.